# Receiving a notification without unwinding the stack in Node

Tags: node.js

I have a piece of code that needs to be cancellable, but can't chunk up the work and post callbacks to be able to check for events before continuing processing. It could however periodically check for some signal in-line. In pseudo-code something like the below (the real code is far more complex):

```
while (true) {
  if (isCancelled()) return false;
  doSomeWork();
  if (isFinished()) return true;
}
```

Implementing `isCancelled` is the challenge. Most notifications need to go back to the event loop to fetch an event. I tried using a socket between the controlling process and Node, and calling `read` which is non-blocking and returns `null` if no data (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size), however in my testing this also appears to require going back to the event loop before any new data appears. (i.e. `isCancelled` above was never true unless there was already data waiting when the above code started running).

Short of writing a native module with OS primitives, is there any other proven pattern for *synchronously* checking for an external signal/notification in Node during processing.

Note: The actual total work takes max 500ms, and ideally can be cancelled within a few ms, so any channels that buffer internally may be too slow. Also, this needs to run on Windows, so any *IX type signals are not an option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130769/check-events-in-node-js-event-loop gives a way to check events in the event loop without executing them - so you can 'peek' and see if your cancellation event is down in the queue, which would happen as soon as some other code puts it in the queue (or if the read event of the socket which potentially will read a cancellation event is in the queue). Doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: Reading those threads, looks like the AsyncListener stuff has gone away in the latest Node releases, and the GetActive* stuff is undocumented and intended for internal debugging (https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1128#issuecomment-90936257), so I'd be loathe to depend on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying AsyncListener API is still here, and is not going anywhere - https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?q=async_wrap.enable

However, in its current state it will not help in your scenario. isCancelled() has to reach out to the external environment and check something in a synchronous way.

A simple way to do this is to create a named pipe in your master process, and then check that the pipe exists in the child process with `require('fs').statSync('\\\\.\\pipe\\signal_pipe_123')`.

You need several-millisecond latency, and pipes are way faster. For some anecdotal evidence, I just checked it on my Windows laptop, and pipe creation takes 0.035ms, while a synchronous stat on a named pipe 0.25ms - more than enough for the use case in question.

Comment: Awesome! You're a genius. This worked beyond my expectations. Even checking several times a millisecond added barely any overhead, and the detection across processes typically happened within the same millisecond.

I added a repo showing the solution at https://github.com/billti/cancellation for those interested.

Answer (score 0):

A hack-like solution is to send signals through the file system. For example, you can create a file named **cancel-***taskid* and `isCancelled()` will just need to check for the presence of that file. Not sure though, if it will fit in your timing constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to your problem may be to use inter-process communication through shared memory. See for example, the [shm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shm) package. I never used it (to be honest, I never used node.js either), but it claims to work on Windows.

Comment: I thought about that but I think that having two different answers is more correct - then the community can decide which solution is better.

Comment: An answer describing multiple options is just fine, better than multiple ones.